# Two plugins extended the same block of smarty in backend(ExtJs)

Tags: shopware

Two plugins extended the same block of smarty in backend(ExtJs).
Both plugins are adding buttons in the toolbar of order listing. Separately they working correctly but if they installed together one of them only is showing.

I tried one of them prepend and 2nd append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions --- in overrided Ext.js component's method should call 
me.callOverridden(arguments) 
instead of 
me.callParent(arguments).